# Invalid precision value error when writing BLOB to Oracle database

Tags: c#, oracle, odbc, blob

I have a table with BLOB field and I'm inserting a binary data into this table. Everything goes well unless I specify a binary data with more than 2000 bytes. In that case I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR [HY104][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver]Invalid precision value. Error in parameter 1
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader, Object[] methodArguments, SQL_API odbcApiMethod)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Is there any reason why the operation could fail with this error for BLOB data type? I tested this behaviour on both Oracle 11.2 and 12 and I see the same behavior.
Here is the code I'm using to update BLOB:

```
public override void WriteBlob(int id, byte[] data)
{
    var cmd = GetConnection().CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "update TB_BLOBS set TB_BLOB=? where TB_ID=?";

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter
    {
        DbType = DbType.Binary,
        ParameterName = "TB_BLOB",
        Value = data
    });

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter
    {
        DbType = DbType.Int32,
        ParameterName = "TB_ID",
        Value = id
    });

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

It works only when data.Length <= 2000. Is there any setting in Oracle I should know about that can make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out why I was getting this error. Behind the scenes .NET framework uses SQL_VARBINARY type to bind my parameters. For Oracle this type is limited to 2000 bytes.

In order to fix this problem I needed to switch to SQL_LONGVARBINARY type. OdbcParameter does this automatically for parameter size > 8000 bytes. So my code potentially works in range size < 2000 and size > 8000. In order to force OdbcParameter to use SQL_LONGVARBINARY I can explicitly set large parameter size. According to [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcparameter.size(v=vs.110).aspx):

> For variable-length data types, Size describes the maximum amount of
>   data to transmit to the server

If I don't specify the Size explicitly it defaults to the actual array size and causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the Blob datalength limit runs into terabytes. However the datalenght limit for char, nchar etc is 2000 bytes. Are you moving data into any such field?
  Another point. Check the buffer length. That could be a limiting factor

Comment: I checked a few times that the data type is really BLOB. I also tried to select inserted bytes with SQLPlus and I'm getting correct results for small byte arrays. I wonder if this could be a driver issue.

Comment: Driver buffer length "DefaultLongDataBuffLen" is set to 1024KB which seems to be enough. Thanks for ideas.

Comment: There is a limit of 400 bytes on insert statement. However, you may bypass it by wrapping it  in a pl/sql Begin... End block

Comment: There is a limit of 400 bytes on insert statement. However, you may bypass it by wrapping it  in a pl/sql Begin... End block  . Also check if setBytes switches to setBinaryStream. By default it is set to 2000 bytes.   It might also be worth checking the SetBigStringTryClob connection property, as it sets to the higher value.   Also it isn't clear from your code-snippet, but the general advice is to use getBlob instead of getString or getBytes